# Nested table title align

Tags: html, css, css-tables

http://egbsystem.net/innosol/prototype/grid_test_pay.html

Just see above the link and check the nested table title and main table title. which are not align properly. I need to align the same height as in the main table title height.

Please help me.

Comment: Unless you're going to ensure that the link provided will stay active *forever* (which is unlikely, seeing as it's called 'test'), it shouldn't be the foundation of your question.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst- sorry. will active shortly

Comment: Link is not active and its not helping anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove

```
height: 50px
```

from the HTML

Also remove the padding from the following classes in css:

```
#paygrid th {
    padding: 6px; /* remove this line */
    border: 0;
}
#paygridaMain th {
    padding: 2px; /* and this line */
    margin: 0;
}
```

The problem is that IDs (#) are much more specific than classes.

You'll also need to deal with the nested table's borders. Either remove the outside borders or remove the borders of the cell it's nested in otherwise you'll have what seems to be a 2px border.

Comment: @craciun - i removed padding but same problem. I put only cellspacing. No put border.

Comment: did you remove the whole line or replace it with "padding: 0"?

Comment: remember that you also need to remove all styles from the HTML as well. (no more style="padding: 0" or style="height= 50px" on ANY of the elements)

Comment: If i remove padding:0 the gird was collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see table titles anywhere, so I'm guessing you mean table headers.

You are applying `height:50px;` directly inline to the nested table headers; but in the main table headers, there is no height prescribed.

You simply need to apply this to the main table headers. You can do this with:

```
#paygridaMain th{height:50px;}
```

Which, by the way, allows you to remove (as redundant) the inline declarations of `height:50px;` on each of `<th>` elements in the nested table.

Comment: i removed inline height and apply (#paygridaMain th) but same problem come out.